# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(S_n \leq \frac{3n}{2}+\sqrt3n)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1,...., X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with p.d.f

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
    4x^2 e^{-2x},& \text{if } x>0\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

and let $S_n=\sum _{i=1} ^n X_i$. Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(S_n \leq \frac{3n}{2}+\sqrt3n)$

How to proceed?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sqrt{3n}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}n$?

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is $\sqrt{3n}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}n$ in your question. We have
$$
P\left(S_n \leq \frac{3n}{2} + \sqrt{3n}\right) = P\left(\frac{S_n}{n} \leq \frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}\right) = P\left(\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{3}{2}\right) \leq \sqrt{3}\right)
$$
Since $\mathsf{E}[X_i] = \frac{3}{2}$ and $\mathsf{Var}[X_i] = \frac{3}{4}$, by [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the random variable $\sqrt{n}\cdot \left(\frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{3}{2}\right)$ follows the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 3/4)$ when $n$ goes to infinity. Then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(S_n \leq \frac{3n}{2} + \sqrt{3n}\right) = \Phi(2)
$$